# Qulatrics Help: loop and merge once, and then never present this loop again

Tags: qualtrics

I have run into an issue with the loop and merge function in Qualtrics. I have 8,000 loops set up, and I am presenting one of those loops randomly to each participant.

When this one loop is presented, I need Qualtrics to NEVER present this loop again. I am not sure how to accomplish this?

I know I can simply separate my 8,000 loops into individual questions and randomize and evenly present in the block options, however 8,000 questions is a lot to compile.

I believe there is a way of doing this in Qualtrics perhaps using javascript?

Can anyone help?

I have also thought of embedding data, and keeping a counter of the question that was presented, but this seemed to be more complex than I originally thought.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: please share your code so that we can see your approach

Comment: Hi Stormie! So I do not have any code, it is completely set up on Qualtrics (survey platform). Unfortunately, I cannot post photos of the Qualtrics survey, but it is just the regular loop and merge function.

Comment: it seems like this particular question may be better posed to the Qualtrics customer service team, I have no experience in Qualtrics and so won't be able to help. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript isn't going to help select your choices.  Here is the easiest approach...

Before your Loop & Merge block set up an MC question with your 8,000 choices, then use Advanced Randomization to randomly insert a subset of 1 from the 8,000 choices, and check the "Evenly Present Elements" box. Use JavaScript to hide the MC question. If it is on the same page as another question, you can hide it with one line of JavaScript since you won't need to automatically click the Next button:

```
$(this.questionId).hide();
```

Set up your Loop & Merge block to loop based on the displayed options in the hidden MC question.